# Making image progress bar in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a progress bar that works with images (empty background progress bar image and filled image)

However, there are 2 problems when I try to do so.

Here is my code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

class CLS_PROGRESS_BAR(ProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, background=None, progress_image=None, font_size=20, **kwargs):
        super(CLS_PROGRESS_BAR, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = background
        self.progress_image = progress_image
        self.progress_event = None
        self.font_size= font_size
        self.label = CoreLabel(text="0%", font_size=self.font_size)
        self.texture_size = None

        self.refresh_text()
        self.draw()

        self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self._progress, 0.5)

    def draw(self):
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Background
            Image(source=self.background, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

            # Draw Progress bar
            Image(source=self.progress_image,pos=self.pos,
                  size=(0.001 if self.value_normalized==0 else self.size[0]*self.value_normalized, self.size[1]),
                  )

            # Percentage text
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(texture=self.label.texture, size=self.texture_size,
                      pos=(self.pos[0] + self.size[0] / 2 - self.texture_size[0] / 2,
                           self.pos[1] + self.size[1] / 2 - self.texture_size[1] / 2))

    def refresh_text(self):
        self.label.refresh()
        self.texture_size = list(self.label.texture.size)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

        self.label.text = str(int(self.value_normalized*100)) + "%"
        self.refresh_text()
        # update
        self.draw()

    def progress(self, rate=0.1):
        self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self._progress, rate)

    def _progress(self, dt):
        if self.value < self.max:
            self.set_value(self.value + 1)
        else:
            self.set_value(self.max)
            self.progress_event.cancel()


# Demo
class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        container = Builder.load_string(
            '''CLS_PROGRESS_BAR:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 100
    width: 500
    max: 100
    background: 'empty.png'
    progress_image: 'filled.png'
    ''')

        return container


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

First problem is that when the process is updated, it randomly shows a white rectangle from somewhere. That white rectangle does not appear when I remove `Image(source=self.background, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)` but I can't still figure out what should I do since it is essential.

Second problem is that when progress bar is stretching to the right, it's height also increases.

`size=(0.001 if self.value_normalized==0 else self.size[0]*self.value_normalized, self.size[1])`

As above, I have set the `size[1]` as `self.size[1]` which is fixed. But, the height of the progress bar keeps growing. (even if I put a static number like `100`)

I have no idea what should I do at this point. Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a few changes that I think make it work as you intended. First got rid of the call to `self.draw()` in `__init__()`. That won't work correctly since the `ProgressBar` size won't be available at that time. Next, I changed the `draw()` method to only create the needed `Widgets` just once, and then update them on every call after that. Also, removed the unused `progress()` method. I added the `allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False` properties to the progress bar image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

class CLS_PROGRESS_BAR(ProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, background=None, progress_image=None, font_size=20, **kwargs):
        super(CLS_PROGRESS_BAR, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = background
        self.progress_image = progress_image
        self.progress_event = None
        self.font_size= font_size
        self.label = CoreLabel(text="0%", font_size=self.font_size)
        self.texture_size = None
        self.firstDraw = True
        self.pbi = None
        self.rect = None

        self.refresh_text()
        #self.draw()

        self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self._progress, 0.5)

    def draw(self):
        with self.canvas:
            if self.firstDraw:
                # Background
                Image(source=self.background, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
                # Draw Progress bar
                self.pbi = Image(source=self.progress_image, pos=(self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + (self.size[1] - self.texture_size[1])/2.0),
                      allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False,
                      size=(0.001 if self.value_normalized==0 else self.size[0]*self.value_normalized, self.texture_size[1]))
                # Percentage text
                Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
                self.rect = Rectangle(texture=self.label.texture, size=self.texture_size,
                          pos=(self.pos[0] + self.size[0] / 2 - self.texture_size[0] / 2,
                               self.pos[1] + self.size[1] / 2 - self.texture_size[1] / 2))
                self.firstDraw = False
            else:
                self.pbi.width = self.size[0]*self.value_normalized
                self.rect.texture = self.label.texture
                self.rect.size = self.label.texture.size


    def refresh_text(self):
        self.label.refresh()
        self.texture_size = list(self.label.texture.size)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

        self.label.text = str(int(self.value_normalized*100)) + "%"
        self.refresh_text()
        # update
        self.draw()

    def _progress(self, dt):
        if self.value < self.max:
            self.set_value(self.value + 1)
        else:
            self.set_value(self.max)
            self.progress_event.cancel()


# Demo
class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        container = Builder.load_string(
            '''CLS_PROGRESS_BAR:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 100
    width: 500
    max: 100
    background: 'empty.png'
    progress_image: 'filled.png'
    ''')

        return container


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Comment: With this code, it only shows progress_bar. percentage text and background are not shown.

Comment: What version of Kivy and Python are you using? And what OS?

Comment: I am currently developing in Windows with 1.10.1 version of Kivy. (Python 3.52) And I am trying to make it to work in Windows, Linux, Android, and ios.

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu with Kivy v1.11.0.dev0 and Python v3.6.6. Perhaps that us the difference, because I see a background, progress bar and percentage text. Since I don't have your images, I am using images of solid colors in their place.

Comment: Actually it shows the text. It was not showing because the background appears to be white and so does the text. Anyway, It is really weird.

Comment: Oh I fixed the problem. It is shown when I add `self.bgi = None` in `__init__` and then do `self.bgi = Image(source=self.background, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)`. It is because the Image object gets garbage collected after the first draw is done.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.